# MS Access: Chart in report blank when underlying query has a parameter

Tags: ms-access, report, ms-access-2016

I have a report in MS Access 16 with a chart in the Report Footer.  The chart and the report have the same data source - a query ("Pipeline Query").  One of the criteria in Pipeline Query refers to a Combo Box on a form (Qtr = forms![Main Form]![Choose_Pipeline]).

The report and the chart at the bottom look great, however I get a popup saying

> "The Microsoft Access database engine does not recognize 'forms![Main
>   Form]!Choose_Pipeline' as a valid field name or expression."

To fix that, I set a Parameter on the query for forms![Main Menu]![Choose_Pipeline].  This does eliminate the error message, but now the chart is blank!  The query still returns the correct data and the data sections of the report work just fine.

Is there something with query parameters that interfere with charts in reports?  Is there a workaround?

*Update: When I wrote this I could have sworn the chart looked fine if the form reference was in the criteria but not the parameter. Now I can't replicate that and any time the query is dynamic and refers to the form at all, the chart is blank.*

Comment: Are you using the new charting in Access 2016 or the old MSGraph control?

Comment: Good question - I don't know. I used the "Insert Chart" button in the Design tab.

Comment: That sounds like the MSGraph tool. I have read that 2016 also has some sort of new charting tool and also read about lots of issues with graphing in 2016 Office 365. I am holding at Access 2010. All of my graphs on report have a RowSource that is an SQL referencing control on report for parameter. None of them are a CROSSTAB query. I don't use dynamic parameterized query objects.

Comment: Tried that - now I get "The Microsoft Access database engine does not recognize '[Reports]![Pipeline Report]![Qtr]' as a valid field name or expression.

Comment: My reports retrieve a single record. There is a textbox named `tbxLabNum` in report header. Graph RowSource: `SELECT M, D, FD, ZD, ZDM FROM GraphProctor WHERE LabNum=[tbxLabNum];`

Comment: Would updating the `QueryDef` of the query to a absolute value for the criteria each time the report is opened, be a suitable workaround?

Comment: Give the absolute value a try before coding for it.